# NSData only has class method "NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(<#path: String#>)"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift

Whenever I try to put `NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL()`, Xcode doesn't recognise it. The only one it recognizes is

`NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(<#path: String#>)`

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: That's because of the way Swift names things. Type in "NSData(c", and you'll get the right choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Swift imports interfaces from ObjC, it treats factory class methods that use Cocoa naming conventions into initializers.

In general, a class method on `NSThing` called `thingWithNumber:` turns into the initializer `init(number:)` and you call it with initializer syntax and the name of the class: `NSThing(number: 42)`. In the case of classes that have both a `thingWithNumber:`-style class method and an `initWithNumber:`-style instance method that does the same thing, both map to the same Swift initializer.

In this case, `dataWithContentsOfURL:` and `initWithContentsOfURL:` become `init?(contentsOfURL:)`. You can find these conversions and more by looking at the Swift interface for a class in Xcode (command-click the class name) or in the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithContentsOfURL:).

Comment: Exactly, so what OP is looking for is ```NSData(contentsOfURL: ..)``` essentially